# Is there a plasmoid that can display at least the title of now playing song while using Bangarang?

Tags: kde, plasma, widgets

I’ve switched to Bangarang as my default player in Kubuntu, but I can't seem to find a now playing plasmoid that works with it.

any suggestions?

Comment: OP are you still looking for an answer? If so, you may need to repost your question as this is flagged for closure. Regards,

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. I am flagging this for closure. Regards,